# ajaxterm: cannot type some characters (j, b, u for sure)

Tags: ssh, terminal

I googled and came up empty.  Anyone have experience with ajaxterm?  Given my login name is "jae", just as on this site, this inability to enter "j" kills ajaxterm for my purposes.  It looked *so* good.  Damn.

EDIT: Dammit, it *was* just Firemacs with its idiotic keybindings.  Removed all the ones which are really "emacsy", and all's fine now.  And the disappearing window was due to me changing the rows/columns, which requires a restart (of a daemon that doesn't show up in pstree, weird).

Answer (score 0):

Is `stty parenb` (character code parity) set on one side of your connection differently from the other side?  That can result in half your characters not being recognized.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but it appears it really was Firemacs's fault.  I removed the bindings to "h" etc and it works now.